# How to change django Response behavior to not nest data in "data" field

Tags: json, django, django-rest-framework

I would like to change how an endpoint is sending a Response

Whenever I use django response like this:

```
return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Model I use:

```
class StationModel(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'station'

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    shortname = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    lat = models.DecimalField(max_digits=50, decimal_places=15)
    lan = models.DecimalField(max_digits=50, decimal_places=15)
```

The response i get from an endpoint looks like this:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "type": "Mymodel",
            "id": "1",
            "attributes": {
                "name": "xxxxx",
                "shortname": "xxxxx",
                "lat": "123.000000000000000",
                "lan": "213.000000000000000"
            }

        }
```

Is it possible to customize response to look like this, or at least get rid of "data" field:

```
        {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "xxxxx",
            "shortname": "xxxxx",
            "lat": "123.000000000000000",
            "lan": "213.000000000000000"
         }
```

Comment: customize your Serializer class... I hope it will work

Comment: Could you provide some details of how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by setting this in settings.py

```
'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
    ),
```